# Orbit ZURB jquery fade in/fade out navigation button on mouseover

Tags: jquery, slider, show-hide

I'm using the jQuery image slider plugin - Orbit. I'm trying to show/hide navigation buttons on mouseover/mouseout. Somehow I managed to do so: http://jsfiddle.net/sherlock85/mZYX9/15/ But when you move your mouse cursor over a navigation button it blinks and it doesn't change the slide.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code. You have to add `div.slider-nav` for `hover`:

```
$("#featured, div.slider-nav").hover(function(){
  $("div.slider-nav").css({display:'block'});
}, function() {
  $("div.slider-nav").css({display:'none'});
});
```

The layer of `.slider-nav` is located over the `#featured` layer. You will lost the focus to `#featured` when the mouse enters `.slider-nav` and it get's the property `display:none`. After that the focus is now over `#featured` again and the property is set to `display:block`. It looks like fast blinking because this will be repeated every time you move your mouse.

Comment: And you could add `$("div.slider-nav").css({display:"none"});` in front of the code to remove the nav buttons on page load.